# Java. printf() Как задать выравнивание таблице

Tags: java, строки, printf

У меня есть меню в программе должно выглядеть так:

```
1. Add task:            n -t
2. View all tasks:         v
3. Add comment:         n -c
```

И так далее...

Я сделал так:

```
    System.out.printf("%-40s%-1s%n","1. Add task:","n -t");
    System.out.printf("%-30s%-1s%n","2. View all tasks:","v");
    System.out.printf("%-40s%-1s%n","3. Add comment:","n -c");
```

Получается не то, отступ от первого слова одинаковый... А меню все равно кривое...

Как правильно это сделать чтобы было ровно как на первом примере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При подстановке второго значения Вы указали дополнение пробелами с правой стороны, а нужно с левой, т.е. без минуса.
Попробуйте так:

```
    System.out.printf("%-40s%10s%n","1. Add task:","n -t");
    System.out.printf("%-40s%10s%n","2. View all tasks:","v");
    System.out.printf("%-40s%10s%n","3. Add comment:","n -c");
```

И вывод на консоль будет таким:

```
1. Add task:                                  n -t
2. View all tasks:                               v
3. Add comment:                               n -c
```